# Anti-DoS WebSockets Best Practices

Tags: denial-of-service, defense, websocket

What are the best practices for thwarting DoS attacks for a WebSocket server?

Is there a comprehensive site or document that can be referenced?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These days it's near impossible to thwart a traffic based DoS without some kind of hefty physical firewall in the network. However, if you're talking about other forms of DoS then there are a few things you can do to help.

- Use asynchronous/non-blocking sockets. A malicious user could open up any number of connections to your sockets consuming all of your available threads. ([Slowloris Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris))
- Control how many request-per-second a user can submit to ensure they aren't flooding your socket
- Ensure the user cannot make the server perform anything too resource intensive

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr:

> "Yes, WebSocket is the ﬁrst way to open an unlimited number of connections to a single server, so it indeed likely needs additional protection to prevent DOS attacks. But we don't really have a way to implement this correctly ..." (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32246#c4)

---

since i'm interested in that topic too, but dont have the time to read all the sources, i'll start this as a collection of (hopefully) useful links; comments to each link appreciated

- [WebSocket Security Analysis (PDF)](http://juerkkil.iki.fi/files/writings/websocket2012.pdf)
- [The Dangers of HTML5: WebSockets and Stable Standards (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563510.aspx)
- [WebSocket Security (Heroku)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security)
- [Websockets 101 (pocoo)](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/9/24/websockets-101/) (mostyl the lessons learned section)

---

update 1 (esp. Blackhat-Presentation)

- [Hacking with WebSockets / BlackHat 2012](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Shekyan/BH_US_12_Shekyan_Toukharian_Hacking_Websocket_Slides.pdf), esp. Sections: Denial of Service - Server / Deploy WebSockets Securely / Secure protocol for WebSockets
- [HTML5 WebSockets - security & new tool for attacking](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/03/html5-websockets-security-new-tool-for.html)
- [HTML5 Web Sockets Changes the Scalability Game](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/html5-web-sockets-changes-the-scalability-game)